# How to enable Redis cache and Loaders using Nest and Mercurius

Tags: caching, graphql, nestjs, dataloader, mercurius

I'm using Nest and Mercurius to create a GraphQL API. So far I was able to create queries and resolvers, but now I want to enable Loaders and Cache to improve performance. The documentation is not clear on Nest on how to do that with GraphQL. On the other side, I don't know how to enable [mercurius-cache](https://github.com/mercurius-js/cache) properly with Nest. Same things with [loaders](https://mercurius.dev/#/docs/loaders).

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { MercuriusDriver, MercuriusDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/mercurius';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ProjectsModule } from './projects/projects.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ProjectsModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<MercuriusDriverConfig>({
      driver: MercuriusDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql',
      subscription: true,
      graphiql: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In projetcsModule, I have my resolvers like this :

```
import { Args, Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Project } from './models/project.model';
import { ProjectsService } from './projects.service';

@Resolver(of => Project)
export class ProjectsResolver {
    constructor(
        private authorsService: ProjectsService,
    ) {}

    @Query(returns => Project)
    async project(@Args('id') id: number) {
        return this.authorsService.findOneById(id);
    }
}
```

My feeling it there is something to add in one of those file (maybe in GraphQLModule options) but I don't know what. FYI, I'm fairly new to TypeScript.